# loading JSON data from an API from javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, cross-domain, jsonp

i need to consume a web api, which is located here 
http://46.253.202.174:8080/ws-api/v1/rest/zdata/codesByJurAndUsage?jur=Boston,%20MA&usg=barber

I don't have any details of how it is implemented or access to the code of the API, I'm just  trying to consuming the API, I can see the JSON return data if i type the url in the browser, but when i'm trying to call the API using $.getJSON, it gave me an access denied error. I understand that its a cross domain issue. I also tried a few other things, like jsonp data type, with no success.  My question is, if i am able to see the results in a browser, shouldn't i be able to get the results from the scripts, or its no necessarily true?
Secondly, is there any other way, if the things i have tried so far was not successful.

thanks

Comment: I think you can get something useful here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3595515/xmlhttprequest-error-origin-null-is-not-allowed-by-access-control-allow-origin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct, you won't be able to load this data via `$.getJSON` due to the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) restrictions. You'll need to load it via JSONP, or, if the service doesn't support JSONP (which it looks like it doesn't), via a proxy. A couple of options:

- You can set up a proxy on your own server via PHP or another server-side language. This will allow you to request the data from your own server, getting around the same-origin restriction. You might look at a project like [Simple PHP Proxy](http://benalman.com/projects/php-simple-proxy/) for this purpose.
- You can use [YQL as a proxy](http://ajaxian.com/archives/using-yql-as-a-proxy-for-cross-domain-ajax) - this sends the data through Yahoo!'s servers and then you can load it via JSONP. Applying this technique with jQuery is [discussed in this article](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/cross-domain-requests-with-jquery/).